# Copy-pasting root-relative URLs in a contenteditable region

Tags: firefox, url, cross-browser, copy-paste, contenteditable

Here's the test: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdarroch/FVd4p/

The goal is to be able copy and paste the image (whose src attribute has a root-relative URL -- `/images/logo.png`) so that the pasted image also has a root-relative URL.

Right now, here's how the different browsers seem to cope:

- In IE8, the pasted image's src will be a root-relative URL.
- In Google Chrome, it will be an absolute URL.
- In Firefox 3.6, it will be just a relative URL.

So Firefox is the problem here. You'll note that when the  is pasted in to the document, the element's src attribute doesn't have the `/` prefix on the URL any more (so it's relative to the page rather than the root of the site), but it somehow manages to divine what the correct relative URL should be.

Is this a case of Firefox trying to be too intelligent and failing? How could I adjust the src attribute on paste so that Firefox will play nice and insert a root-relative URL?

Comment: What is a "hierarchical" URL? I've never heard of it.

Comment: Whoops, poor choice of wording. Sorry about that. I've updated the question.

Comment: What's the actual problem? As your jsFiddle example shows, you get a fully qualified URL in Firefox if you use `getAttribute("src")` rather than the `src` property, and it's not too hard to get from that to the URL relative to the root of the site.

Comment: I've just bumped into this I think this is the relevant firefox bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=613517

Comment: That bug looks like the same problem as here, yeah.